# Clarifying the purpose of notificationSender in NSNotification's addObserver function

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

Could someone kindly clarify the purpose of `notificationSender` in the `addObserver` function of `NSNotification`?

Here's the explanation from the Apple docs:

```
notificationSender
The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.
```

We use notifications to respond when a video has ended. The code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
```

where `playerItem` contains the video in question. However, passing `nil` for `object` seems to have no discernible effect.

It's better for us to use `nil` instead of `playerItem` because we wouldn't need to create another class variable.

What's the risk in using `nil`, and what's the advantage in using `playerItem`?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to be specific with the `notificationSender` is if you have chosen a notification name that other objects (that you don't want to listen to) are going to send to you.  Specifying a `notificationSender` is akin to a delegate relationship, where leaving it nil means that absolutely any object could send you a notification with the same String and you would process it.

In practice, this is rarely an issue as long as you pick notification strings that are unique.  You'll see people using things like `com.my.app.name.notification` or `kMyAppNotification` for precisely this reason.

And as to the specific line of code you linked, I don't actually know the implementation details, but I'm assuming if you added a listener with the `notificationSender` property pointing to an object, you also need to remove the same listener with the `notificationSender` property set, or else risk a memory leak by not removing observers.  But I'd have to read the docs again to figure that out.